# mysql backup password without root home

Tags: mysql, my.cnf, centos-7, cron

What's the best way to provide a MySql root password (`~/.my.cnf`) to cron job without root to have the home folder?
the server I'm using is centos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the best way to provide a MySql ... password

Using a separate configuration file, as described in [the Manual](https://oracle-base.com/articles/mysql/mysql-password-less-logins-using-option-files).

> What's the best way to provide a MySql **root** password

You should not use *any* high-level credentials for Application connectivity.  Not **root**, not **mysql**.
*Always* created a dedicated account for your Application, grant it appropriate permissions, and use that.

Why?  You should always keep the Best Tools in the ToolBox for *yourself* - so that you can clean up the mess made by *everybody else*!

> ... without root to have the home folder?

The Linux **root** account will *always* have access to the mysql home folder.
By design, **root** must have access to *everything*.

Comment: Thanks `mysql --defaults-extra-file=~/scripts/extra.my.cnf` is like exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysql_config_editor`

```
mysql_config_editor set -G project_name -u database_name -p -h localhost
```

Notes

- The -p prompts for the password
- -P 3306 for port (default 3306)
- -h could point to a remote server
- Other options are possible

Docker example:

```
mysql_config_editor set -G o8016 -P 8016 -u root -p -h `hostname`
```

Usage:

```
mysql  --login-path=o8016
```

mysql_config_editor hides the pwd in a 'dot file' in your home directory is such a way that access is limited to you and, of course, "root".